# Issue with site reformatting on mobile sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

So in my javascript for my site, I have `$(window).resize(function(){` and then it continues to reformat the site for the new browser width...
However, this is triggered on mobile sites when a user zooms in (you know like when you can't see a picture too well on your phone so you use your fingers to zoom in), and the website reformats for the "new" browser width.

How can I avoid this? Should I use a different event to catch when the browser actually changes size, should I just have something catch if the user is using a mobile device or not, or is there something else I should do?

Thank you in advance for any help or advice, and I apologize for a rather vague question for a specific issue!

Comment: Post your meta viewport

Comment: there are widths you can look at that won't change, `outerWidth` i think is one. memorize it onload, compare in your resize event, and if they match, return early.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">